# How to fetch only part of a Firebase RealTime database, and not the entire database?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rest, firebase-realtime-database

I'm making a page with React.js where the first 3 posts are loaded from a server and displayed in the html. When the user scrolls to the page bottom, I want to load 3 more posts.

My intention is to save bandwidth by only loading what's necessary. This means that I **should not** download the entire database and then only display a fraction of it.

I successfully did the exact same exercise, but I fetched the data from a local json-server. I used axios to perform the get request. Axios provides a convenient 'transformResponse' argument, where you can configure the request. There I performed a slice to the array of data prior to retrieving it, which is exactly what I needed.

Now I want to do the same, but by loading the data from Firebase instead.

So far I've managed to retrieve the data from my Firebase database and display the posts. I've done it like this:

```
database.on('value', snapshot => {
  this.setState({
    posts: snapshot.val()
  });
});
```

The problem is that this way what I get is the **entire** database. I don't want that. I want to only fetch 3 posts.

Answer (score 0):

Firebase retrieves only the data under the location you attach your listener to.

So if you have a node called posts, you can retrieve just that node with:

```
database.child('posts').on('value', snapshot => {
  this.setState({
    posts: snapshot.val()
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

May I know how you structure your database?

If you identify these posts by Id such as this

```
root -- posts --- post 1
              --- post 2
               .
              --- post n
```

Therefore you can loop through many posts you want like this

```
firebase.database().ref('root/posts/' + postId).on('value', snapshot => {
  this.setState({
    posts: snapshot.val()
  });
});
```

You can also group posts for just once calling API instead of looping:

```
root -- posts --- postGroup1 --- post 1
                             --- post 2
                             --- post n
                     ...
              --- postGroupN --- post 1
                             --- post 2
                             --- post n
```

You can view more here at the [Firebase real-time database docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write?authuser=0)